# does not contain configuration file ver.yaml

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Trying to upload a new version of my php app and I get the following error:

> appcfg.py: error: Directory [redacted] does not contain configuration file ver.yaml

What the heck...there is not a single google result for ver.yaml.

Comment: *there is not a single google result for ver.yaml.* there is now, since you asked a question about it ;-) Try uploading with gcloud instead of appcfg

Comment: Yep...I should have tried that. It works. Still no idea what causes that error though.